# How to parse logs in OS X?

Tags: c#, objective-c, macos, logging

I have an app that writes to it's log file all the time:
[image: log]

How can I read only it's new information at the moment it is added into the log?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  You want to Console app to display only the very latest log message from your app?

Comment: @stevesliva yep. The first app adds lines at the end of the log. I want to get them, not all the file every time.